# Print database values in the main layout

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5 for my project. I have a view file `layouts/app.blade.php` which is extended by all the views. I have stored the application name , email in the database .... Now I need to show those data in my `app.blade.php`..

How do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? It sounds like you are very new to Laravel. It is an amazing framework and you are going to love it but it will take some learning. Please don't post questions without first trying to spend some time learning about the problem. There are a ton of tutorials on how to get started with Laravel but the best Laravel/PHP tutorials on the web can be found at laracasts.com. Check out https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/4 for a cast specific to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as @DutGriff said, it seems to be that you are too new to laravel framework. Just dig in a bit and you get something called `Service Injection` in blade. Now, answer to your question:

1. Open you `app.blade.php`
2. Go ahead and type the following at very start of `app.blade.php`

   `@inject('model_name', 'App\ModelName')
   {{{ $model_name = $model_name->where('app_name', 'app')->get() }}}`
3. And then, just access it anywhere like:

   `{{ $model_name->name }}`